# Should we take the time zone of the candidates into account when voting?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

This question is mostly aimed at the current moderator team.

Do you think that the time zone of the new moderators matters, and if so, which period of the day is most in need of a new moderator?

Or do you think that the time zone only makes a small impact, and the most important thing is the increased capacity overall?

Comment: More mods in or hovering around the Asia Pacific time zones would be nice.

Comment: *Should we take the time zone of the candidates into account when voting?* - there's nothing stopping you from doing so but I wouldn't let it distract you from casting your votes based on who you feel are the most suitable candidates.

Comment: Is considering their time zone assuming too much?  Perhaps it would make more sense to take into consideration the hours they would generally be available to moderate?